# ISDEV : error -6259: Internal build error

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2010, installscript-msi

I am getting above mentioned error message. I have recently updated my **[Thwarte certificate](http://www.thawte.com/)** because it had expired and now i am not able to build my installer. I have used pfx file and my password for signing.

Following is complete details of error message-

```
ServiceInstall table successfully built
Started signing EFAF.tmp ...
Successfully signed: EFAF.tmp
Started signing EFB1.tmp ...
Successfully signed: EFB1.tmp
Shortcut table successfully built
Signature table successfully built
TypeLib table successfully built
UIText table successfully built
Upgrade table successfully built
Verb table successfully built
_Validation table successfully built
Searching project for extract-at-build components...
Building scanned MsiAssembly records
Building scanned MsiAssemblyName records
Validating Custom Action sequencing
Embedding manifest SetupExe.Highest.manifest into setup.exe
Checking string table references...
Generating RC file: _ISUser_0x0409.rc
Building dialog 12053
Building dialog 12058
Built 2 dialogs into resource file: _ISUser_0x0409.rc
Building RES file: _ISUser_0x0409.res
Compiling resource DLL: _isuser_0x0409.dll
Resolving strings...
Language English (United States) built
Embedding manifest SetupExe.Highest.manifest into setup.exe
Started signing EFB7.tmp ...
Successfully signed: EFB7.tmp
Building CAB files...
Data1.cab built
Files built
Media table successfully built
Started signing certificate.msi ...
Successfully signed: certificate.msi
ISDEV : error -6259: Internal build error [D:\Builds-WIP\Gulliver\MT_RR2_Installer\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
ISDEV : fatal error -5087: Stop at first error [D:\Builds-WIP\Gulliver\MT_RR2_Installer\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
Setup\InstallerWithPrerequisitesFromWeb - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
Log file has been created: <file:\Builds-WIP\Gulliver\MT_RR2_Installer\Binaries\x86\Debug Build\Installer\Setup\InstallerWithPrerequisitesFromWeb\LogFiles\1-13-2012 10-04-07 AM.txt>
```

I can see that it is able to successfully sign the msi but fails afterwards. I have no idea what is going on. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a file signed with this certificate, does it appear signed? Is the full path to the root certificate available and trusted? It's possible that there's an intermediate certificate which needs to be installed on the build machine.

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to reply to this thread. Thank you Michael, it was indeed an Intermediate certificate issue. I was missing "thawte code signing ca-G2" certificate. I installed it and it works fine now. Thank you.

Comment: @SanjaySingh IF the post was helpful, please upvote the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Although late to the party, it might help someone searching error 6259 and 6258

When using InstallShield 2014 version(which is out of support) the problem might be when signing with a timestamp server.
In the settings.xml file located under "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2014 SAB\Support\0409" replace the line

```
<DigitalSignature Timestamp="http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll"/>
```

with

```
<DigitalSignature Timestamp="http://timestamp.digicert.com"/>
```